# "This worked" vs "This would work"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

Good day everyone, please help me with my confusion.

**"This worked" vs "This would work"**

First, **"This worked"** is in the past tense, and **"This would work"** is in

the past tense too since **"Would"** is the past tense of **"Will"**.

In short, they are both in the past tense, but my question is what are their differences? And

what makes them  different from each other?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The word "would" in that case was not used as the past tense of "will." According to Merriam-Webster, the word "would" can also be used to "talk about a possible situation that has not happened or that you are imagining." (Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would)

Answer (score 1):

As @acheigrec says,

`This worked` - Gives the idea of something that You fixed in the specific point in the past.

`This would work` - You're creating an expectancy which something works, I think that It fits better with a conditional clause, for example

`If I were you, probably I would kill me!`

[Would](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/would.html) -
[Simple Past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)

Comment: Thanks ThMoraes for sharing your views! However in the case of "This would work", if it does give the idea of a possible object or situation "can" work and assuming which something will work in some point in the future, then how does "This would work" differ from "This will work" and "This works" if they all refer to some point in the future? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh man, my mistake, I made a mistake when I referred `would` as "Future", actually `will` is used as Future and `would` as Conditional, now `This works` refers to the Present

Comment: Your conditional sentence doesn't work: if she accepts it, she **will** kiss me (it will happen); **would** doesn't work since once the *if* clause is triggered, the result implies a result that will be satisfied.

Comment: Wait, I wil change! but I'm imagining that she would kiss me, perhaps that cannot happen, maybe She could accept my gift and whatever, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

As long as *would* is considered with a condition, you invoke an imaginary situation set in the present:

> This would work *if* you did it. (You don't do it, so it doesn't work.

Now, the use of *would* can be considered as a repeated action or habit in the past (adding more context):

> When I was a child, this *would* always work. (Repeated action in the past that it's different now in the present.)

So basically as you were told, the past simple only adds info. of a completed action in the past on a specific time. Either *would* introduces a conditional sentence or a repeated action.